# Sony Xperia stuck in boot loop due to no free space

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop

My partner has a Sony Xperia Z3 compact that has been complaining of low space (~16 MB free) for weeks before now finally refusing to boot and it has become stuck in a boot loop. I have tried a number of key combinations to try and get it into recovery mode but none have worked and I have read that Sony Xperias do not have this enabled. The phone is not rooted.

Is there anything I can do to get either free up some space to try and get it to boot or to get the data off the device or should I consult a specialist data recovery company?

Many thanks

Comment: Very often you need to hold power and volume key up or down *simultaneously and for a long time* like half a minute

Comment: @beeshyams Yes I've read that these buttons need to be pressed when the led flashes blue, but it never turns on at all before going into a boot loop

Comment: I would suggest you keep trying to push the buttons for long because in a boot loop situation, you will not always see those prescribed indicators that show up normally // This may not guarantee work but it did for me twice (two different devices in boot loop). No harm trying

Comment: Try to see if it will connect to ADB.. It is doubtful but worth a try. If adb devices detects the device then fastboot should be able to bring it out  of it. Otherwise lets just hope it inherited Android's legendarily short battery life.